# Migration from CSV: how to define a default value for autoincremental id field?

Tags: 8, migrations

I run migrations from CSV using Migrate Source CSV, Migrate Plus and Migrate Tools modules and it works fine.
The result of one of these migration is a custom entity which key is a 'id' field that has the 'AUTO_INCREMENT' property in the database.
Here is my `migration_contractssubscriptions.yaml`

```
id: migration_contractssubscriptions
migration_group: null
label: 'Contract Subscriptions migration from CSV'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: /mypathto/migration_ContractsSubscriptions.csv
  delimiter: ';'
  enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
process:
  id: id
  contract_id: contract_id
  member_id: member_id
  sharedwith_member_id: sharedwith_member_id
  comment: comment
  quantity01: quantity01
  quantity02: quantity02
  quantity03: quantity03
  quantity04: quantity04
  owner_id:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:contract_subscription'
```

I'd like to get rid of 'id' in my csv file and let the migration process handle the value of the resulting id.
I tried to remove `keys: - id` and `id: id` but I get an error...
How can I achieve that?

Comment: I assume `id` is the primary key of your custom entity, so simply removing `process: id: id` should work. Do not remove or change fields from `source: keys:` in production - Migrate's internal mapping table would get out of sync. If you change the source keys, rollback and drop the mapping table first. Look for `migrate_map_FOOBAR` tables in your DB.

Comment: Once removed `id: id` from `process:` I have this error:  
`[error]  La migration a échoué avec l'exception de plugin source : id is defined as a source ID but has no value.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood that `keys` in `source` is the way to make each row of the csv file unique. It may be anything.
So I changed to:

```
  keys:
    - contract_id
    - member_id
```

I removed `id: id`from `process`and it works!
The value of `id` field in the database is properly auto-incremented.

Comment: how do you deal with the required source:ids key then ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question :-( As said in the answer, the source keys is made with `contract_id` and `member_id`.

Comment: I had an error saying that the ids key was required but not given. But it may be caused by something else as your code works today. ty